# how to add multiple links to parts of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

how would I add multiple links to an image. Linking an image I would just wrap it with `a href`. I would have an image of a tree with apples then I would want to add a link to each apple in the image. How would I do this?

I was thinking of using position absolute but seems tedious especially when trying to make it mobile responsive of moving the links.

Comment: this can be done with the `map` tag

Comment: ...but this is for a completely different purpose. Better use absolute positioning.

Comment: [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) is built for that kind of thing but it's just as tedious as positioning some elements over the image.

Comment: so either way both are tedious to do

Answer (score 2):

Apple Tree

You can use [Image Map Generator](https://www.image-map.net/)

```css
.wrap {
    transform: scale(0.3);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/tree/76337-vector-fruit-tree-apple-download-free-image.png"
        usemap="#image-map">

    <map name="image-map">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#1" coords="626,247,775,130" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#2" coords="495,265,632,378" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#3" coords="620,437,750,558" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#4" coords="346,829,467,931" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#5" coords="579,937,707,1041" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#6" coords="885,289,1029,386" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#7" coords="1082,540,1210,652" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#8" coords="1268,926,1403,1035" shape="rect">
        <area target="" alt="" title="" href="#9" coords="1025,1096,1171,1206" shape="rect">
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: I see lets say if i want to make it mobile responsive? would i be able to change the coords in media query css

Comment: There are two options to make it responsive: 
1. Using JS. (Unnecessarily complicated for this purpose) 
2. Using CSS by changing the scale. Example: @media screen and (max-width: 800px) { .wrap { transform: scale(0.2); } }